# How to fix "deprecated form of raising exception" warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
import sys
import traceback


class MyException(Exception):
    pass


def bar():
    [][1]


def foo():
    bar()


try:
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception as ex:
        type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        raise MyException, ("You did something wrong!", type, value), tb
except LolException:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

It gives me the "deprecated form of raising exception" warning in PyCharm. How can I fix it? I need to save the original exception info.

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, because I need to save the original info

Comment: The actual answer to this question is only in a *comment* to an answer in the other question. Is this still a legal duplicate?

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki Thanks! Can I somehow add info about original exception type too?

Comment: As long as this question is closed as duplicate, you should probably ask that in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try raising the exception this way:

```
import sys
import traceback

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

class LolException(Exception):
    pass

def bar():
    [][1]

def foo():
    bar()

try:
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception as ex:
        raise MyException(str(ex)+" You did something wrong!"), \
                          None, sys.exc_info()[2]
except LolException:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File deprecated.py, line 21, in <module>
    foo()
  File deprecated.py, line 17, in foo
    bar()
  File deprecated.py, line 14, in bar
    [][1]
__main__.MyException: list index out of range You did something wrong!
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the "None" in this case?

Comment: If you read the [Python 2.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) on the `raise` statement closely, the third paragraph says that "If the first object is an instance, the type of the exception is the class of the instance, the instance itself is the value, and the second object must be `None`." You have to include some value there in order to be able to provide the optional third object, which must be either `None` or a traceback object if present.